# Syntax error near SQL As

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

guy i cant find the whats causing the syntax. Its a little bit long and dizzy. It gives

> "Incorrect syntax near as"

on the bottom script which i cant find whats the cause of it. The finish output will be only one column with a very long long long string on it.
Hopefully a new set of eyes can help me. Thanks

```
        Select 'TUEF'+'11'+(RTRIM(APPMNBR) + SPACE(25 - LEN(APPMNBR)))+
         (RTRIM('') + SPACE(10 - LEN('')))+SPACE(8)+'1000'+'A'+
         ('000010000' + SPACE(9 - LEN('000010000')))+'PHP'+
        'EN'+'08'+'TT'+'009'+'000000'+'NA03N01'
        +'01'+
        CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMFSTNM))) <= 9 
        then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMFSTNM)))
        else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMFSTNM)))
        end +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMFSTNM,30))))


        +'02'+
        CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMDLNM))) <= 9 
        then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMDLNM)))
        else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMDLNM)))
        end +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMMDLNM,30)))


        +'03'+
        CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMLSTNM))) <= 9 
        then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMLSTNM)))
        else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMLSTNM)))
        end
         +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMLSTNM,30))))

        +'04'+
        CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMOM))) <= 9 
        then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMOM)))
        else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMOM)))
        end
        +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMLSTNM,40))))

        +'0608'+
         +(LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(APPMDOB,2))))+
         +(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(APPMDOB,5,2))))+
         +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMDOB,4))))+

        +'ID03I01'+
         Case when APPMTIN <>'' then
                CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMTIN))) <= 9 
                then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMTIN)))
                else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMTIN))) 
                end 


              when APPMTIN = '' and APPMSSS <> ''  then 
                CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMSSS))) <= 9 
                then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMSSS)))
                else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMSSS)))
                end 
              end


        + Case when APPMTIN <>'' then (LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMTIN,50)))) 
              when APPMTIN = '' and APPMSSS <> ''  then (LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMSSS,50))))
              end+

        '02'+
         Case when APPMTIN <>'' then 'TIN' 
              when APPMTIN = '' and APPMSSS <> ''  then 'SSS'
              end +

        'PA03A0101'+
        LEN(
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR1,30))) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR2,30)))  + ' '+
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR3,30))) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR4,30)))
        ) +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR1,30))) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR2,30)))  + ' '+
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR3,30))) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR4,30))) +
        '06'+
        CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMZIP))) <= 9 
                then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMZIP)))
                else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMZIP,9))))
                end + LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMZIP,9)))+
        '0701R'+
        'A0201'+

        LEN(
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA1,30))) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA2,30)))  + ' '+
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA3,30))) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA4,30)))
        ) +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA1,30))) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA2,30)))  + ' '+
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA3,30))) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA4,30))) +
        '06'+
        CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMEMPAZ))) <= 9 
                then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMEMPAZ)))
                else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPAZ,9))))
                end + LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPAZ,9)))+
        '0701F'+
        'PH03P01'+
        '03'+
        CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMPHONE))) <= 9 
                then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMPHONE)))
                else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMMPHONE,30))))
                end + LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMMPHONE,30)))+
        '0501F'+
        '0601M'+
        'ES02**' as Textfile
```

Comment: How many columns do you actually expect here?  Your current query is just a single really long string concatenation.  Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: just one column with a veerrrrrrrrrrrrrryyyyy long string...

Comment: correct this as  `+'02'+
        CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMDLNM))) <= 9 
        then '0'+ LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMDLNM)))
        else  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMDLNM)))
        end +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMMDLNM,30))))`

Comment: yes found it... thanks @YogeshSharma...

Comment: @YogeshSharma.. you got idea for this "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ID03I01' to data type int." and its already on a quote.

Comment: Additionally, there are double "+" right before text ID03I01

Comment: @user3751759 u should look and use `cast` where u find some conversation issues.

Comment: @YogeshSharma even though in the script its already in 'ID03I01'?

Comment: @YogeshSharma When you commented `and it will work` under my answer, did you actually test the query, or were you just guessing?

Comment: TIPS: (1) Divide and conquer. Delete sections of code to narrow down where the problem is. (2) Use consistent formatting to make mistakes more obvious. (3) If you follow principals of a [mcve] with emphasis on ***minimal*** you're likely to resolve your trivial error much more quickly than by asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for yogesh sake... it did answer the question for the syntax error of AS... but still the query didnt work..

Comment: @CraigYoung thanks for the idea. Ill try it now

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have tested then after commented u

Comment: @user3751759 edit the question show us ur db structure or sample table structure.

Comment: @CraigYoung yeah.. i found the problem. The very long string... with numbers.. its trying to convert it into a numeric which what im not trying to do

Comment: @YogeshSharma... sorry, how much i wish i can but i cant...

Comment: For Everyone.. its the LEN(), it returns a numeric value and it tries to convert other else on the script to numeric too.. @CraigYoung thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
    use below correct query


Select 'TUEF'+'11'+(RTRIM(APPMNBR) + SPACE(25 - LEN(APPMNBR)))+
     (RTRIM('') + SPACE(10 - LEN('')))+SPACE(8)+'1000'+'A'+
     ('000010000' + SPACE(9 - LEN('000010000')))+'PHP'+
    'EN'+'08'+'TT'+'009'+'000000'+'NA03N01'
    +'01'+
    CASE when  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMFSTNM))) <= 9 
    then '0'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMFSTNM))))
    else  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMFSTNM))))
    end +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMFSTNM,30))))


    +'02'+
    CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMDLNM))) <= 9 
    then '0'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMDLNM))))
    else  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMDLNM))))
    end +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMMDLNM,30))))


    +'03'+
    CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMLSTNM))) <= 9 
    then '0'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMLSTNM))))
    else  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMLSTNM))))
    end
     +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMLSTNM,30))))

    +'04'+
    CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMOM))) <= 9 
    then '0'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMOM))))
    else CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMOM))))
    end
    +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMLSTNM,40))))

    +'0608'+
     +(LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(APPMDOB,2))))+
     +(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(APPMDOB,5,2))))+
     +(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMDOB,4))))+

    +'ID03I01'+
     Case when APPMTIN <>'' then
            CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMTIN))) <= 9 
            then '0'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMTIN))))
            else  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMTIN))) )
            end 


          when APPMTIN = '' and APPMSSS <> ''  then 
            CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMSSS))) <= 9 
            then '0'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMSSS))))
            else  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMSSS))))
            end 
          end


    + Case when APPMTIN <>'' then (LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMTIN,50)))) 
          when APPMTIN = '' and APPMSSS <> ''  then (LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMSSS,50))))
          end+

    '02'+
     Case when APPMTIN <>'' then 'TIN' 
          when APPMTIN = '' and APPMSSS <> ''  then 'SSS'
          end +

    'PA03A0101'+
   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), LEN(
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR1,30))) + ' ' +
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR2,30)))  + ' '+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR3,30))) + ' ' +
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR4,30)))
    ))+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR1,30))) + ' ' +
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR2,30)))  + ' '+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR3,30))) + ' ' +
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMADDR4,30))) +
    '06'+
    CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMZIP))) <= 9 
            then '0'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMZIP))))
            else  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMZIP,9)))))
            end + LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMZIP,9)))+
    '0701R'+
    'A0201'+

    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA1,30))) + ' ' +
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA2,30)))  + ' '+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA3,30))) + ' ' +
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA4,30)))
    )) +
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA1,30))) + ' ' +
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA2,30)))  + ' '+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA3,30))) + ' ' +
    LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPA4,30))) +
    '06'+
    CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMEMPAZ))) <= 9 
            then '0'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMEMPAZ))))
            else  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPAZ,9)))))
            end + LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMEMPAZ,9)))+
    '0701F'+
    'PH03P01'+
    '03'+
    CASE when LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMPHONE))) <= 9 
            then '0'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(APPMMPHONE))))
            else  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMMPHONE,30)))))
            end + LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(APPMMPHONE,30)))+
    '0501F'+
    '0601M'+
    'ES02**' as Textfile
```